# Request with an input for a initialized Object

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I want to call an Object with a specific name which i type into the console.
I know a way would be with a switch statement but it should work also with new initialized Objects.

here is an example of code.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String nameObject=null;
    // Create a new Object with a specific name
    System.out.println("Type in the name of the Object");
    try {
        nameObject = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    Person NewPerson = new Person(nameObject);


    System.out.println("Which Person do you want to have?");
 String requestName = reader.readLine();
//search for the object which has the name requestName
// after this i want find the right person with an reader.??
```

Comment: did you get any value in the nameObject variable?

Comment: Yes there i ask for the name of the person wich becomes the name of the new object. Intializing works fine the problem is when i have several person objects an i want to call one with a specific name.

Comment: can you show your Person class?

Comment: Actually i do only have a constructor in the person class which expects the name as string. I wrote this code just as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first you can make your **Person** class as the following :

```
public class Person {
    public String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

then create an array of Person objects but you can use list of Person objects :

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person> ();
```

then add the created person into the list:

```
persons.add(newPerson);
```

and after getting the **requestName** variable, iterate through the list, as follows:

```
for(Person p : persons) {
    if (p.name.equals(requestName )) {
        // you got the desired person
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But with this i would have to create for every new initialyzed object such an if statement. I am loking for a method which searches an object wich has the name that was typed in after the second output question.

Comment: can you explain it more in detail?

Comment: I edited the last lines of my code i hope it will be clearer now.

Comment: i edited my answer, you should better take a look at that

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thank you very much.